# Suggester not returning results

Tags: solr

I am using default configuration (as below). My text field has document text. How do I get suggest working?  I already tried build=true in command line.

```
 <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>      <!-- org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst -->
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>     <!-- org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.HighFrequencyDictionaryFactory --> 
      <str name="field">text</str>
      <str name="weightField">suggestweight</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>

  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
      <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

Schema.xml has..

```
   <field name="suggestweight" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: Exactly how did you invoke building of the suggestions? To what URL are you making the request to get suggestions? Are there an suggestion field included in the response? Do you get any errors on your log file? Do the log say anything? Have you tried a more minimal configuration?

Comment: I used ../suggest?suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.q=america

Comment: This is the default configuration, except that I added <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str> No errors in logs. Logs just say hits=0

Comment: I tried changing field type as text_en and when I do /spell, I get this in logs.. tionary=wordbreak&spellcheck.count=10&isShard=true&spellcheck.alternativeTermCou
nt=5} status=0 QTime=0